# What are the standard Python meanings of "version" and "release"?

Tags: python, versioning, python-sphinx, pypi, semantic-versioning

What is the standard Python meaning of "version" and "release"? In particular, I'm confused about how to reconcile Sphinx's use of the terms with their use in [PEP 0440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/).

For example `sphinx-quickstart` prompts for a version with

> Sphinx has the notion of a "version" and a "release" for the software.
>   Each version can have multiple releases. For example, for Python the
>   version is something like 2.5 or 3.0, while the release is something
>   like 2.5.1 or 3.0a1.  If you don't need this dual structure, just set
>   both to the same value.

and creates a configuration file containing

```
# The short X.Y version.
version = ...
# The full version, including alpha/beta/rc tags.
release = ...
```

But [PEP 0440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/) describes the "release" as having he form `N(.N)*` seems to use the term "version" to refer to the "full version" as used by Sphinx (i.e., its "release").

What is a Python "version" and how does it differ from a "release"? Specifically, does Sphinx represent standard interpretations of these terms?

Answer (score 3):

It's actually very consistent. That `N(.N)*` isn't referring to the version it's describing how to format the numbering of a *release*:

> The release segment consists of one or more non-negative integer
>   values, separated by dots

If you're wondering how a release is defined, see [PEP 0426](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0426/):

> "Releases" are uniquely identified snapshots of a project.

So yes, Sphinx does represent the standard interpretation

Comment: Yes, but "one or more non-negative integer values, separated by dots" doesn't reconcile with "including alpha/beta/rc tags". Also the term "version" doesn't seem to be defined anywhere (and is kind of circular as used in the Sphinx `config.py` comments). Is there an explicit statement of what that term means somewhere?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius It's a distribution identifier, as described in PEP 0426: *"The distribution's public or local version identifier"*, 
and then in PEP 0440: *"The version scheme is used both to describe the distribution version provided by a particular distribution archive, as well as to place constraints on the version of dependencies needed in order to build or run the software"*